# zsh: find with '*' in path

Tags: zsh, quoting, glob

At the moment I'm playing with zsh+prezto and really like it so far, but now I have problem with find.

Some preparations:

```
zsh> mkdir -p /tmp/1/2/3
zsh> mkdir -p /tmp/1/3/4
zsh> find /tmp/1
/tmp/1 
/tmp/1/3
/tmp/1/3/4
/tmp/1/2
/tmp/1/2/3
zsh> ls /tmp/1/*/*
/tmp/1/2/3:

/tmp/1/3/4:
```

Trying to use find with globbing:

```
zsh> find /tmp/1/*/*
find: `/tmp/1/*': No such file or directory
```

Trying to quote the path:

```
zsh> find '/tmp/1/*/*'
find: `/tmp/1/*': No such file or directory
```

Doing to same in bash:

```
bash> find /tmp/1/*/*
/tmp/1/2/3
/tmp/1/3/4
```

Which config option do I have to set to make this work in zsh?

Comment: It is rather strange that it works with `ls` but not `find` as glob expansion is done before the command is run, so it should make no difference at all. With `zsh -f` you can start a zsh without loading configuration files. Does it work there? You could then check for differences in the output of `setopt` to see which options could be responsible.

Comment: Thanks. The options weren't the problems, but it helped my find the real one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

```
> grep find .zprezto/modules/utility/init.zsh
alias find='noglob find'
```

Now I have to do some research to find out if there's a good reason for this.

Comment: One reason to use `noglob find` is to be able to pass wildcards for `find` to use in the name matching. Example: `noglob find . -iname incompleteName*`

Comment: Thanks. I think I prefer having to write `find . -iname 'incompleteName*'` (with quotes) when it allows me to use something like `find /home/*/files/ -iname fullName`.